# How to use SKProductsRequest in a InApp Purchase, fetching non-consumable products from my own server in iOS7

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm at the end of my new application: An In-App purchase application with my own server for videos to sell, but I'm trapped in the purchasing process.

According Apple Docs this can be done, but I've read all Apple documentation about in-App purchase and I can't see how to manage this.

The products to sell will be hosted in my own server, so I suppose than I have not to register products in iTunes Connect, isn't it?  the intention is to be able to add new products to sell without entering iTunes connect.

So that, is it necessary to use `SKProductsRequest`?

I suposo than I have to use

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product]
```

so that "product" has to be an SKProduct (or not?), and... where it comes from? from SKProductsRequest object? but SKProductsRequest gets products from iTunes connect and not from my own server.

And, what about product identifier? Apple Docs explain how to get products id... through Json ...but once i have this products ID. what else?.

[image]

Well I think my ignorance on this subject is amply demonstrated.
I would appreciate some main points to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked Apple and their answer is: all products to sell in an IAP must be registered through iTunnes Connect, and all those productos must be reviewed by Apple reviewers.

So that, for me, it has no sense what Apple sais in its documentation, what I put in my question (screenshot), for example, it has no sense to "Fetching product IDs from your own server", if is mandatory to register those products ID in apple too, is redundant.

In fact, fetching product IDs from Apple is better because you get, also, what products are able to sell, and which not.